# best output format

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, file-format

i'm working in the Video Sequencer and currently outputing using the H264 format.
unfortunately it's far too compressed for final product. the AVI uncompressed is way to large.
any advice would be appreciated
also....must include audio.

Comment: Use ordinary Avi or Mov. But you can't render both video and audio at the same time. You need to render video separately and merged them together with another app

Comment: Israel Bamidele this is not true, you absolutely can render Audio and video at the same time.

Comment: H 264 has lots of different settings, and can go from crap to barely noticeable artifacts. It's one of the best encoding compressions. If you don't like the compression even with high quality levels of settings, you have to accept the big size of the file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's highly oppinion-based.

Comment: I think he is asking for more codec, like H.265?

Answer (score 3):

## There is no **best** format.

If you want quality with minimal compression it comes in large file sizes. If you want smaller files, then the question becomes how much image compression is acceptable to you and the application you want the images for.

Usually if the images are going to be further processed (like compositing or color-corrected) you need an uncompressed file format like EXR, and it is only after you are done with all processing that you choose an efficient delivery format.

Even if you are not going to do post-processing, then it is advisable to render as image sequence, and do the encoding later. At this stage you can add sound to the pictures as well.

This workflow will allow you to try different encoding settings and formats until you find one that satisfies your needs.

So the "best" format will be for you, and only you to decide, your "best" format might not be the "best" for others